# React Native Auth good practice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, authentication, expo

How can I implement authentication so that I don't have to make the user log in every time the app is opened?

what I thought of was to have the user log in once and, if the operation is successful, to save the login credentials (username and password) in the AsyncStorage so that every time the user opens the app I'm going to log in automatically using the credentials that I saved after the first login.

Is it a good practice or are there other methods or solutions? My only requirement is that the user does not have to log back in every time they open the app.

Comment: Typically you'd save the token you get back from the server after the user has logged in, not the username and password. You can consider using [expo secure storage](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) to store the information securely so that it persists.

Comment: thank you so much! I'm going to use this approach